# How can I change owner of mounted directory?

Tags: server, permissions, mount, external-hdd, chown

I'm using ubuntu server 20.04 on raspberry pi 4 and I want to change the owner of the external drive for changing permission for my server. But I can't change the owner even using `sudo su` and `chown`. I changed the ownership while the drive is unmounted, but it overwrites and changes to `root`.

Before mounting USB flash drive on "usb128":

[image: Permission and owner of before mounting to the media directory]

After mounting on "usb128":

[image: permission and owner of after mounting to the media directory]

*Note: I want to change the owner during the drive is mounted.

Comment: I just tried this operation and `sudo chown me:me /mountdir` worked as expected. I did this while the device was mounted. I `umount`ed it and mounted it again: still owned by me. Maybe post some error messages from `/var/log/syslog`, if there are any?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but `sudo su` is not what you want. Instead you want `sudo chown....`

Comment: What's the filesystem on the external drive? Does `sudo remount -o rw,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sdX /media/usb128` help (for Windows filesystems)

Comment: "I changed the ownership while the drive is unmounted" - then whatever you changed had nothing to do with the drive.

Comment: @waltinator it worked! Thank you very much!